# Twitter Login and post in Flex 4 Applicationa

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, twitter

I just want to know how to add a twitter login in a flex 4 appliation. Bascially on click of a button it should ask for login, and twitter post button which will post the tweets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few resources out there that cover using Twitter with actionscript / Flex:

- [Twitter AS3 OAuth Lib with Flex 4 example](http://soenkerohde.com/2010/01/twitter-as3-oauth-lib-with-flex-4-example/)
- [Connect to Twitter from AIR example](http://www.flex-blog.com/connect-to-twitter-from-flex-example/)
- [AdvancED Flex 4 (Google Books)](http://books.google.com/books?id=iNVFVenMtEYC&pg=PA433&lpg=PA433&dq=flex%204%20twitter&source=bl&ots=aonNG8qg7b&sig=sLrJJvOo2TGqYaXOlf2yJ5pGeWk&hl=en&ei=Ls4VTrnhMe6nsALhlNlQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBQQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=flex%204%20twitter&f=false)

Comment: It would be great if there is some working example for twitter login and post for Flex web app